# ManagedBuildManager CDT import

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I need to use the ManagedBuildManager but my Eclipse is not seeing it. What is the import statement for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this on my own. I needed to get the library that contained the ManagedBuildManager.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core,
org.eclipse.cdt.core
```

to MANIFEST.MF, section Require-Bundle. In Eclipse UI editor for plugin.xml
and MANIFEST.MF this setting can be found in tab 'Dependencies', section
Required Plug-ins.